# How to delete a folder which named as \ using terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, rmdir

I Created a folder  in desktop using GUI named   ' \ '  after when i tried to delete that folder using terminal by rmdir . then i cant able to delete it . what is the reason for that ???

Comment: Please give the error message you get when trying to delete.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `\` is a special character that is intercepted and used by the shell ("expanded") before the `rmdir` program gets it.  So you need to quote the character to indicate that the shell should not mess with it.  There are (at least) two ways:

```
rmdir \\
rmdir '\'
```

Note on the second one: single quotes, not double (`\` is expanded inside double quotes).

Give that, as an exercise, how would you delete a directory called `-\`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the character for deletion, `rmdir \\` , add a `-v` flag for verbose `i.e. rmdir -v \\`

```
$ mkdir \\
$ ls -lrt \\
total 0
$ rmdir -v \\
rmdir: removing directory, `\\'
```

Comment: The `-v` flag is handy here ++

Answer (score 1):

You just need to give bash a command line that has an argument of a single `\` (after bash expansion).

The easiest one is: `rmdir '\'`

The most basic is to escape the `\`: `rmdir \\`

Or even inside double quotes: `rmdir "\\"`

Using an octal escape number: `rmdir $'\134'`
or `rmdir "$(echo -e '\0134')"`
or `rmdir "$(printf '%b\n' '\134')"`

Using an hexadecimal value: `rmdir $'\x5c'`
or `rmdir "$(echo -e '\x5c')"`
or `rmdir "$(printf '%b\n' '\x5c')"`

Answer (score 0):

Type rmdir '\' to delete that folder

Comment: This will delete the folder with name \